# Taking the Linux Install CD out during Installation?

Tags: rhel, drivers, system-installation

I'm installing rhel and need to install a driver during installation. The plan is to 'linux dd' at the boot promt and install then.

However, I just wanted to know if there would be an issue with removing the Linux install cd at that time to install the driver using a cd, and if so, if there is a workaround.

This is because both the driver and Installation are on cds and I only have one disk drive. Moving 1 to different media is not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure about RHEL, but Debian and in general most distributions offer to remove the CD and install the necessary firmware at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on when exactly you will do this and what is required to install the driver. The most likely answer is no, it won't be a problem.

When a live CD is booted, an initial ramdisk is first loaded which contains most of the tools necessary to run your system. If you are at a prompt, these tools are already loaded and you should be able to remove the CD with no trouble.

You will need it if you go on to install though since the files will need to be copied from the CD.

Comment: it's no issue to swap the cds back after, my constraint here is that both the OS and driver are on disks, and there's only one cd drive, so I can only have access to one at a time. I'll give it a go though

Comment: @Dave yes, I understand. There should be no problem.